# A Karrass-Solitar or Ivanov-Schupp for profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $F$ be a nonabelian free profinite group, $H \leq_c F$ finitely generated with $[F:H] = \infty$. Must there be some $\{1\} \neq N \lhd_c F$ such that $N \cap H = \{1\}$?

Comment: You first need to assume that $H$ has infinite index.

Comment: @YCor I just forgot it, edited now.